# What's the best word to describe the harsh, unaesthetic exterior of a building?

Tags: word-request

[image]

Take the image of this building for instance, a good percentage of people would say that it's not pleasant to look at. No colorful tiles, no fancy arcs. In short, it's "harsh-looking." I'm looking for a word that best describes buildings such as this one which are not aesthetically pleasing. Buildings that give off an ominous vibe or make you feel uneasy. If you search photos of headquarters of most intelligence agencies, naturally you'll see that their exteriors are very unwelcoming and harsh. As you can tell from the explanation I've provided, I've used the word "harsh" twice! Not that I think it doesn't get the job done, it does, but I'm looking for a more precise word.

Comment: The word for an ugly building and the word for a ominous looking building will probably not be the same.  So are you looking for two words?  Or a word for ugly **and** ominous?

Comment: This isn't quite an answer, but [brutalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brutalist_architecture) is an architectural style which is often behind such "harsh," "imposing" or "ugly" buildings.

Comment: I'd argue it's rather the photograph that makes the building harsh/unwelcoming/gloomy/gritty... The weather, the age of the building, and [its incompleteness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Soviets_(Kaliningrad)) are other contributors. It's an example of post-war Soviet architecture (focus on mass-production and cheap materials like concrete), which, to an extent, is a sub-style of Brutalist architecture

Comment: @AndrewTobilko: My favourite Russian movie is [*The Fool](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3560686/) (2006)*, which shows how badly things can go wrong with such buildings. It's nothing peculiar to Russians though - we had [Ronan Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronan_Point) in the UK, for example (and more recently, [Grenfell Tower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grenfell_Tower_fire)).

Comment: Another possibility is [forbidding](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/forbidding).

Comment: It is sometimes called a **carbuncle**. There is even an architectural prize for the worst building of the year, called the [Carbuncle Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbuncle_Cup).

Comment: @WeatherVane that's an interesting word

Comment: Strangely, this meaning has not found its way into the first three dictionaries I consulted for a reference, but I since found it in [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/carbuncle).

Comment: One alternate word which comes to mind is “Soviet”.

Comment: @ChrisMelville well the word "Soviet" does carry political connotations with it, doesn't it?

Comment: Can you be much more specific? How could there be such a word, unless the harsh, unaesthetic exterior of any such building was the same?

Comment: @Fermichem There is nothing particularly Soviet about that building. Not to mention the Soviet Union favored very different architectural styles throughout its history. If anything, the so-called [Stalinist architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stalinist_architecture) is the first thing that comes to mind when I hear "Soviet building". Less eerie, more grandiose. That is not to say such harsh-looking concrete buildings weren't common in the USSR, they were and many of them still exist.

Comment: @Fermichem Now this one a house...   Made my day. Thanks for asking this. Priceless.

Comment: It might be colloquial, but a lot of people would simply say ''industrial''.

Comment: I'd say "Space invaders", as this building looks directly inspired by the characters from that game, or vice versa [https://www.google.com/search?q=space+invader&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X]

Comment: This question is asking for an opinion, not really a fact.  The multitude of valid answers seems to be testament to this.  Perhaps the question should be closed?

Comment: @Tom "industrial" came to my mind too, it aptly conveys that idea of "utility" over "significance" (usefulness over beauty)- thanks for suggesting it.

Comment: It's so odd that the *comment* proposing "brutalism" as an answer has a higher score than  the actual *answer* explaining how "brutalist" fits. @TypeIA maybe you could delete your comment since there is already an answer covering it? The answer has garnered some downvotes, and since a comment can't be downvoted, it seems unfair to preserve it.

Answer (score 35):

This building has a specific architecture related to it.  The word is [brutalist](https://www.designingbuildings.co.uk/wiki/Brutalism).

Brutalist architecture was a design style that first used concrete in large buildings, where the concrete forms created the style and pattern of the building's external features.  It favored "strong" large boxy shapes, was popular in the 1950's, and is now considered by some to be very ugly.

The name is related to the word "brutal" which comes from the same Latin root word "brutus".  Brutal means

> savage or violent

The second definition

> punishingly hard or uncomfortable

The second definition of brutal closely describes some of the elements you are trying to express.  "Its brutal square windows gave no sign of the life inside."

Comment: An article on "Why are there so many brutalist buildings in Washington, D.C?" https://www.ncpc.gov/news/item/52/ which has a building that's very similar in style to this one.

Comment: According to the article you quoted, the name came 'Béton brut' (raw concrete).

Comment: @NomadMaker Correct, but English "brutal" and French "brut" both derive from the same Latin word, so ultimately it's the same difference and the comparison here is fair.

Comment: @TypeIA: That's the same sort of logic that says "awesome" and "awful" mean the same thing in modern English usage; etymologically, sure, but etymology does not describe the current meaning. The French meaning of "raw" is sufficiently different from "savage", "violent" or "punishingly hard or uncomfortable" (even if it can *also* be used with other words to mean those things) that claiming "Brutalist" derives from the English word "brutal" is incredibly misleading, even if modern critics might view Brutalist architecture that way.

Comment: "Brutalism" comes from the French "brut" which comes from the Latin "brutus".  "Brutal" comes from the Latin "brutus".  In English, the same core words can take on different meanings, from the paths they take before English "collects" them into the mess of a language we have.  At its Latin core, "brutus" means "dumb or stupid".  Which is where this commentary is going fast :)  But seriously, all of the English "brutal" focuses on negative traits of mostly unrefined people, while the French focuses on mostly negative traits of unrefined items.  It's not a leap to shift between the two.

Comment: @EdwinBuck It **is** a leap—“brutal” is not an etymological ancestor of “brutalism.” Your answer claims it is. Therefore, your answer is wrong. You have “leaped” from one branch of linguistic evolution to another. Are they related? Absolutely, they share a common ancestor—in the Latin. But that makes them cousins, which isn’t the relationship you have indicated. And it means that the divergence in the English and French lineages here is extremely relevant—if “Béton brut” is the typical French word for “concrete,” then the people who named “brutalism” intended none of the connotations you name.

Comment: @KRyan Perhaps it is a leap, but today, people's descriptions of the buildings aren't "raw concrete"  They're described as being ugly, harsh, uncomfortable, and foreboding.  It's today's current view of what has become "ugly" by poor implementation and changing tastes that make many current day associations of "Brutalisim" to "brutal".  That's the same way that "awesome" stopped becoming "fear inspiring" and became "cool".

Comment: @KRyan I cannot fathom why you are motivated to this degree, but I updated it.  I hope you sense of justice is fulfilled.

Comment: @KRyan This is the *English* Language Learners SE site. What it's called in French isn't really relevant. Brutalism = the philosophy/school of being brutal, which Brutalism very much is.

Comment: @KRyan Your attempt to see only one sentence in the article is impressive.  Why would they write,  if Brutalisim only meant "raw concrete", "In 2006, three architects from Boston, Massachusetts initiated a rebranding campaign to relabel Brutalism as Heroic architecture. The effort attempts to remove the negativity of the original term while preserving its reference to its scale and substance"  (also from the same source)  Finally, French speakers didn't coin the word. English architects coined the word.  (again from the same source).

Comment: @EdwinBuck I’m done; you’re right I’d missed the nationality of the term’s coiners, though I think it matters little if Béton brut is what they had in mind. Or even if they simply had both in mind, as wordplay—that would be worth mentioning. And I never said the term lacked negative connotations—my contention was that your source states that the original intended meaning was neutral, so the etymological argument doesn’t make sense. Mostly, I think it’s interesting and not someone casually aware of the style would necessarily know (I didn’t), so I can’t see why you would avoid including it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I see your point and mostly agree, but I think you read too much into my comment. The meanings are for sure not identical but they _are_ related, etymologically and semantically. I felt the earlier comment (which I was replying to) was disputing the etymological connection.

Comment: The country name 'Britain' has the same root - according to legend it was founded by Brutus of Troy - whether you therefore consider Britain to be savage, violent, uncomfortable and hard is up to you.

Comment: There are many buildings that may not be strictly "brutalist" but would be considered "harsh" or without "aesthetic ".  Besides, many burtalist building facades have a definite aesthetic, which the OP is not looking for.

Comment: Using the name of the specific style may or may not be what the OP is going for, but it's a really good suggestion. Brutalist architecture tends to have severe lines and a looming, top-heavy design as seen in the OP's photo, as if the building it ready to tip forward and crush you at any moment. "Internationalism" is the more skyscrapery 'plain glass rectangle' look that dominates most city skylines today, which OP is presumably not referring to. Though it's stern and austere in its own way, I wouldn't think of International style as "harsh".  That's pretty specific to brutalism.

Comment: @PeteKirkham Interestingly enough, the oldest clear naming of Britian seems to come from the Romans.  Some have suggested that attributing the origin of 'Britain' to the Latin 'Brutus' may be ultimately derived from Isidore of Seville's popular 7th-century work Etymologiae, in which it was speculated that the name of Britain comes from bruti, on the basis that the Britons were, in the eyes of that author, brutes, or savages.  The Brutus stories are chronicled 200 years later, where a brute, Brutus of Troy, who kills both his parents name the island after himself (at least in on version)

Answer (score 21):

An appropriate word would be [austere](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/austere)

> stern and cold in appearance or manner
>
> markedly simple or unadorned

An austere building is one that is simple, without any fancy adornments, and gives the sense of being harsh, or unwelcoming.

I'd also note that *aesthetic* is subjective; some people find this architectural style to be very pleasing.

Comment: @Fermichem No problem. I actually answered the question as you framed it (I think), but there's another answer that answers a slightly different question, i.e. "what do you call a building with a harsh unaesthetic exterior?" In case that's what you're looking for, the other answer is better, and you might want to edit your question to clarify that.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  While brutalist architecture is the obvious go-to for 'harsh building appearance', there are plenty of ominous, unforgiving looking buildings that aren't brutalist.

Comment: The word "austere" is typically associated with pared-back beauty; an 'ascetic' aesthetic. In my opinion, the pictured building is not austere. I think other answers/comments have suggested more suitable words such as: forbidding, ominous, severe.

Comment: Wow, I'm not a native speaker. But seeing the word "austere" somehow gives me the impression of "serene", which is then bringing images of "calm, enjoyable". Didn't know that it means the opposite.

Comment: @Xavier I don't agree, or else the word pair "austere beauty" wouldn't be so common. Compare especially to political/economic austerity, where it definitely doesn't have those connotations

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure if it's a colloquialism local to Ireland, but this is what we would call "Institutional".

That is having a no-frills functional design, built cheaply disregarding any care for how it looks, generally housing a state institution for something distasteful such as Sewage Treatment Plants, Prisons for dangerous criminals, Revenue Collectors . . .

Comment: Similarly, the word that came to mind was "industrial".  The building owner cares more for the inside than "how it looks to the neighbors"  For example, Prince's Paisley Park Studio building looked like any other industrial building in the area ...on the outside.

Answer (score 7):

utilitarian, unadorned, plain, grey, gloomy, glum, washed-out, tragic, bunker, fortress, slapped-together, uninviting, imposing, unwashed, weathered, armored, abandoned, run-down, neglected, unassuming.

It might be better to use more than one word. I like "an unadorned, weathered, industrial building"

Bringing in aesthetic values doesn't paint a good picture because tastes change and every person has their own idea of what beautiful is. Visit the modern art section at the Met.

Comment: I always like combining words to create a rich description; and, it is important to keep in mind that many examples of what is current change over time.  So names that tie directly to a specific movement make more sense than names which indicate "current", "modern", or "contemporary", if your description is supposed to not follow the changing items which can be seen as current, modern, or contemporary.

Comment: thanks for a thorough answer.